# How can I determine when a verb can be used intransitively?

Tags: verb-usage

While investigating possible translations for the sentence (from I. Asimov's, I, Robot):

> She encircled his neck with rosy arms and hugged tightly.

I hit upon:

> Sie einkreiste seinen Hals mit rosigen Armen und umarmte **ihn** fest.

But I would like to establish whether the "ihn" is strictly required or not. I do not trust Reverso, dict.cc or Pons. They are mistaken too often. And DWDS and Duden do not appear to address the question. Where can I get accurate answers about such a question?

Comment: Not your question, but "einkreisen" would be a weird thing to do with someone's neck (which doesn't translate to *Hals* here, that would sortof imply she tried to strangle him). A common way to put this would be "Sie schlang ihre rosigen Arme um seinen Nacken und umarmte ihn fest". A native speaker maybe wouldn't even use "umarmen" here, but rather "Sie schlang ihm ihre rosigen Arme um den Nacken und drückte ihn fest"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strictly speaking, an object would be needed for "hug" in English, and the only reason that Asimov gets away with not including one is the magic of ellipsis. It pretty obvious who she's hugging, so the "him" isn't necessary for the meaning. "Hug" can be used intransitively in English, but only if there are two or more people involved and they're hugging each other. In German this would be handled with a reflexive pronoun: *Sie umarmten sich.*

In general, dictionaries tend not to distinguish between strictly transitive and optionally transitive. DWDS doesn't even use transitive/intransitive labels. It does put *etwas* or something similar in the definition if the verb is transitive, but it still doesn't always tell you if the object is unnecessary. Fortunately DWDS does have a wonderful usage database which allows you to discover for yourself how often a verb is used with an object or not. Even if a verb is 100% transitive in theory, the object might still be dropped using ellipsis. My advice is that if you're not sure then be conservative and include the *ihn*. It may not be the best translation but it won't be an incorrect translation; as a non-native speaker you can't expect to be able to phrase every sentence as well as a professional writer.